# Videojs-YouTube parameters doesn't work with Angular 10

Tags: angular, youtube, video.js

[YouTube API Parameters Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters)

Goal: I want to remove all *related videos suggestions*, *share button* and *controls*:

1. Video.js library versions:

```json
"@angular/cdk": "10.2.7",
"video.js": "7.10.2",
"videojs-youtube": "2.6.1",
```

2. This is my default config file in the angular component

```js
config: any;

this.config = {
  responsive: true,
  controls: true,
  playbackRates: [0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2],
  plugins: {},
  html5: { nativeTextTracks: false },
};
```

3. This is where I set up the Youtube plugin after `ngAfterViewInit()`

```js
this.config.techOrder = ['youtube'];
this.config.sources = [{ type: 'video/youtube', src: this.youtubeUrl }];
this.config.youtube = { modestbranding: 1, wmode: 'transparent', controls: 0, iv_load_policy: 3, rel: 0 };
```

Let me know if you need any other info to resolve this issue as early as possible!

Comment: Could you provide the html code?

Comment: Sure @MarcinRestel. 

Here's the Angular HTML code. 

``` lang-html
<video #videoPlayer class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" id="speak_video"
 controlslist="nodownload" width="640" height="360" controls="controls" preload="auto"> 
 <p class="vjs-no-js">
  To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
  web browser that
  <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
   supports HTML5 video
  </a>
 </p>
</video>
```

Let me know if you want to see on the component side code. Thanks so much!